# Trying to use transpose matrix function in R but it turns out to be the t-test

Tags: r

So I have a matrix called `X` and was trying to use the transpose matrix function `t(X)` in R to get the transpose of the matrix. But the function `t(X)` returns the t-test for X, while I am pretty sure the matrix X is input correctly (when I try the code `class(X)` it shows that its a matrix. Do I need a package to use the transpose matrix function?

Comment: What packages do you have loaded? This is most likely caused by loading a package that defines a new function `t` that masks the `t` function in base R.

Comment: call `base::t(X)` instead